# Image matching on the live video feed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, opencv, image-processing

I would like to search & match a captured photo on the live camera feed.

**Here are the detailed actions:**

There are two buttons. One is using to capture an image and the other one is using to activate the live video. I'm planning to search & match the previously captured image on the live video feed.

Presently, I'm trying-out the [BloodAxe/OpenCV-Tutorial](https://github.com/BloodAxe/OpenCV-Tutorial) to achieve my goal.

**Expected Output:**

[image]

**Here are some of my findings:**

1. I analyzed the [Wikitude SDK](http://www.wikitude.com/developer/documentation/ios), tried out the Point of Interest. However, this not seems to be promising.
2. I didn’t find a good OpenCV library example to achieve my goal.
3. I analyzed the [OpenCV iOS - Video Processing](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html#opencviosvideoprocessing) tutorial.
4. I analyzed the [AR Marker tracking tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/40870/augmented-reality-ios-tutorial-marker-tracking) by Raywenderlich, However the mentioned [String SDK](http://www.poweredbystring.com/) is no longer available.

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is a bit hard to follow.

You want the user to first pick an small image that they will search for later in the camera feed?

Then, you want to feed video from the camera through your app and search the ENTIRE video feed for the image you're searching for? Or do you have a small section of the screen that the app will look for?

Can you impose some reasonable restrictions on the image search? Like it needs to be in the correct orientation and aligned within a few degrees, and sized within a certain range of the target image?

From what I've read the openCV library is a good choice for this, but image recognition is an advanced subject and you might have to dive into OpenCV and write your own OpenCV module to implement what you're after.

Comment: yeah. I want feed the video from the camera and search the ENTIRE video feed for the particular image.

Answer (score 0):

I had implemented a similar task in Android once. I had used OpenCV Java bindings to do so. My implementation was inspired by this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html). The advantage is that your detection will be rotation and scale invariant. I had used - STAR Feature Detector and FREAK Feature Descriptor and BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING for Descriptor matching.

CAVEAT - There should be sufficient features on your object to be tracked. Moreover, there was a lag between consecutive frames which could be felt.

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please provide more details about your implementation?